# How to debug node / express?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, visual-studio, debugging, express

When I start my app using `'npm start'` at the command line I can browse it at :3000

.. but not when I start it using `'node app.js'`

when I try `'node --debug app.js'` I get a console window with the message

> "Debugger listening on port 5858"

With Visual Studio and the node toolkit I get the same. With Eclipse and Enide I get the same.

I've tried using Nodes built in command line debugger,  but after the debug> prompt appears issuing the continue or next step commands does nothing, and I can't browse the app at :3000

I've installed node-inspector, and after `'node --debug app.js'` I can see app.js in the node-inspector chrome tab :8080, but can't browse my app at :3000 and can't get breakpoints to work.

I guess that to get debugging working I need `'node app.js'` to run, and not be using `'npm start'`..

What important node configuration detail have I missed?

Why is my app not browsable when using `'node app.js'` ?

Any advice is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actually starting the app in two differnet ways using different code - one which includes the debugger and one that does not.

If your running a default Express 4 setup, if you check the package.json file you will see this section:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

That is the file that is executed when you run `npm start`, so running node `app.js` is actually a different script.

If you take a look at `bin/www` you will see the debugger is invoked:

```
var debug = require('debug')('myapp');
```

To run use:

```
DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www
```

If you are starting using NPM, you can add it to the package.json or use exactly the same command from the cmd line:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG=myapp node ./bin/www"
  }
```

Comment: Okay I see...  'npm start' is invoking the start script as defined in 'package.json', great that explains a lot... and I can tell visual studio/enide to use 'npm start' instead of 'node app.js' .... or use the command line...  but where do I put 'DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www' so that node-inspector will attach?  in the .bin/www script ?

Comment: @Kickaha I have not used node-inspector but it looks like you may be confusing the node-debug lib with the debug lib. Just had a real quick look at node-inspector and it looks like you just install globally and then kick it off using node-debug so `node-debug ./bin/www` should do it.

Comment: Okay I found that for Visual Studio I needed to hack the 'myApp.njsproj' project file to add bin/www as the startup file..  For Eclipse it is set in Run > Run Configurations > Node Configuration.. (I couldn't set breakpoints using Eclipse, but could use it in conjunction with node-inspector.. )  understanding that bin/www was a file and not a directory was key so cheers.. One other editor very good at express debugging I found was 'MS Code'. It's still in beta but is a much better tool for the job.  I'll go back to the built in debugger if I need to debug in a terminal.  Thanks again Ben.

Comment: Check out WebStorm (part of the intelliJ family). Its not free but by far the best IDE I have found for node. Great debug tools, integrated testing etc.